# Spring : Is this member variable thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, thread-safety

```
@Service    
public class InfoService {
    private Info currentInfo;

    public void initInfo(String data) {
        currentInfo = new Info(data);
    }

    //blarblar...
}
```

If this is not thread-safe, my service methods should be changed to hold "currentInfo" as its parameter.
I don't want to make duplicate parameter code, so I make it as member variable of service.
Of course, this code works perfectly on me, but I worry about this can be thread-danger.

"currentInfo" can be thread-danger?

Comment: Let's worry about it compiling before we worry about it being thread safe...

Comment: Ignoring that this wouldn't even compile, without knowing the use pattern or specific problem this is impossible to answer. As-is, your private variable isn't `volatile` so that's certainly not "thread safe" in terms of being safely published. I'd highly recommend picking up a copy of [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601)

Comment: I think that's dependent on is your service is singleton or not if it is singleton then multiple thread can access currentInfo but it is not singleton then only thread from this object used this variable
correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after initialization you would have singleton instance of this class, now imagine two threads have reference to this object,

`thread-1:` sets currentInfo and starts calculating something based on it (*I assume you are using it in other calculation with your `//blarblar...`*)

`thread-2:` After thred-1 starts using it meanwhile thread-2 resets it

Comment: *generally* stateful shared mutable objects are sign of thread-unsafe code